# FFmpeg audio disappears in the middle of the video

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding

I've been trying to convert a sequence of PNG files to a video with some sound (mp3 or wav). It pretty much works with different codecs and quality settings for both video and audio.But the audio disappears somewhere in the middle of the process

Here are my options. I tried copying audio, encoding to various codecs from mp3 and wav with various bitrates etc.:

```
-report -threads 0 -f image2 -i "files/%%d.png" -i "audio.mp3" -start_number 0 -frames 1500  -vcodec mpeg4 -q 20 -acodec copy -r 25 -y "video_out/seq.mp4"
```

This gives me a video with the problem that audio stops being played about half way through.

Here's [the output from `ffmpeg`](http://pastebin.com/cgWqhK2A). Doesn't show any issues.

Please let me know if you know where this could be coming from. I've been banging my head for a long time trying to resolve this.

I'm on FFmpeg for Windows (Feb 1 2013 18:47:10 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)).

Comment: So, you're sure the audio file is longer than the video duration? I don't see anything unusual either. Maybe you can give it a shot with the latest build from [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), and if that doesn't work, [report a bug](http://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html) with a minimal sample to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but IIRC `-start_number` is an input option, so it should go before `-i "files/%%d.png"`